# MobileFirst POST javascript array to java array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an array in javascript that I am trying to pass to my mobilefirst java adapter. I call my adapter like so,

```
 myArr = [1,2,3];
 var sendPost = new WLResourceRequest(
                "/adapters/MyAdpater/path",
                WLResourceRequest.POST
        );
var formParam = {"arr":myArr};
sendTicketPost.sendFormParameters(formParams);
```

Then in my adapter I can have my method and get the param

```
public JSONObject postAdapterFx(@FormParam("arr") List<Integer> myArray) {}
```

Currently when I send this I just get a 400 error and it is because the adapter doesnt like the form param as that type, so what else could I set myArray to in the adapter? I can send it as a string and then convert the string to a `List<Integer>` in the java but that is really messy and I would like to avoid doing that.

So how can I pass this array?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in body with request.send(yourArray). Then you can read it in Java with buffer.

Example from knowledge center

```
var request = WLResourceRequest(url, method, timeout);
request.send(json).then(
  function(response) {
    // success flow
  },
  function(error) {
    // fail flow
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take an extra step before sending the form data to the adapter. `sendFormParameters` only accepts objects with simple values i.e., string, integer, and boolean; in your case `arr` is an array.

Create a utility function that will encode the form data, you can use the following:

```
function encodeFormData(data) {
  var encoded = '';

  for(var key in data) {
    var value = data[key];

    if(value instanceof Array) {
      encoded += encodeURI(key+'='+value.join('&'+key+'=')); 
    } else {
      encoded += encodeURI(key+'='+value);
    }

    encoded += '&';
  }

  return encoded.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Then you will need to update your code as follows:

```
var myArr = [9,2,3];
var sendPost = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/Cool/users/cool", WLResourceRequest.POST);
var formParam = {"arr" : myArr};
sendPost.sendFormParameters(encodeFormData(formParam));
```